# Limit maven-surefire-plugin to a specific test source root

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

Given a Maven module with multiple test source roots, how can we limit `maven-surefire-plugin` to run tests only from a specific one?

The use case is as follows: I would like to have multiple test directories, and pick them based on maven profiles, e.g. `-P only-tests-in-directory-A` or `-P only-tests-in-directory-B`.

I am aware about `include` and `exclude` configuration options, but they only work on package/class names, which is not great, because in all test roots the tests might be named similarly.

There is also a `testSourceDirectory` configuration option, but according to documentation it only relates to testNG reports.

Comment: Can you explain why you have ` multiple test source roots` ?? A single module should only have a single directory containing the tests `src/test/java` and resources in a supplementatl directory `src/test/resources`... The question is why you need such things? Can you elaborate more in detail what exactly your problem is?

Comment: @khmarbaise There are different test types in each module. Think of "Integration Tests", only they don't spin up local containers, but query already deployed instances elsewhere. Like production tests. I don't want to mix them with regular unit test, since they serve a different purpose and should only be triggered explicitly. But codewise, they are related to the given module.

Comment: @Oliver ^^ Above are some details about the project structure.

Answer (score 1):

I think @khmarbaise's question is incredibly relevant. OP, you should consider the complexity of your project structure. Why do you have multiple test source roots and not just multiple packages? Are you trying to separate IT and other tests or something?

Regardless, you could use the Build Helper plugin's `add-test-source` goal:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>add-test-source</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <sources>
          <source>src/it/java</source>
        </sources>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

You can also use the `add-test-resource` goal to add resources.

More about the plugin here: https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/

Hope this helped!

Comment: I replied with more details in the comments to the question. Thanks for the suggestion to use `build-helper-maven-plugin`, I'm aware of it. There are several problems with this approach. First, Intellij Idea won't recognize those directories unless you make those profiles explicitly activated all the time. Second, when activating a specific test type I would like to run ONLY those tests, and not run unit tests, which will be always included in the approach that you're suggesting.

Comment: @IvanBalashov take a deep look into my anser...

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing in Maven is to follow conventions over configuration. This means to name integration tests like `*IT.java` instead of something else. If you have a single module setup they belong within the same module if you have multi module setup it sometimes make sense to have a separte module for integration tests.

Furthermore it means integration tests have to be executed by maven-failsafe-plugin which has to be activated by using it like this:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>integration-test</goal>
          <goal>verify</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

It is of course necessary to define the plugin version via an appropriate pluginManagement section in your pom file or in your common parent.

A pluginManagement configuration could looke like this:

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
      <configuration>
        <skipTests>${skipUTs}</skipTests>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
      <configuration>
        <skipTests>${skipITs}</skipTests>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

In combination that give the opportunity to run unit tests via:

```
mvn test
```

If you want to run integration tests as well (incl. unit tests):

```
mvn verify
```

Sometimes it makes sense **not** to run integration tests during a release or alike which can simply be achieved by using (sometimes people use profiles for such things):

```
mvn verfiy -DskipITs
```

To make it possible to run supplemental tests (whatever we call them) you could do that via test suites. That needs the following dependencies in JUnit Jupiter like this:

```
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.1</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
    ....
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```

And really using the following dependencies (And yes you need both of them):

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-engine</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

You can define a test suite like the following:

```
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.IncludeClassNamePatterns;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectPackages;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SuiteDisplayName;

@Suite
@SuiteDisplayName("Suite Demo - First Suite")
@SelectPackages("packageName.suite1")
@IncludeClassNamePatterns(".*SD")
class FirstSuite {

}
```

By using a particular package for say your System-Integration Tests Part one etc. Those test will be included there... The naming pattern here as defined by the annotation `*.*SD` or whatever naming pattern you like (but be carefull not to interfere with the usual ones of [surefire](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes)/[failsafe](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#includes) plugin)

A particular suite class could look like this:

```
class SuiteOneSD {

  @Test
  void first_add() {
    Fraction sum1 = new Fraction(5);
    Fraction sum2 = new Fraction(2);

    assertThat(sum1.add(sum2)).isEqualTo(new Fraction(7));
  }
```

You can activate a suite simply on command line via:

```
mvn test -Dtest=FirstSuite
```

This will only those tests defined by the `FirstSuite`. If you want to combine those suite with your unit tests you can simply do that via (be careful about the quoting it is necessary):

```
mvn test -Dtest='FirstSuite,*Test'
```

You can also execute the suites in a different phase (at the time of the integration tests). This will execute the unit tests including the suites.

```
mvn verify -Dit.test='FirstSuite'
```

If you want to combine the suites with the usual integration tests:

```
mvn verify -Dit.test='FirstSuite,*IT'
```

The given properties give you the opportunity to control if unit- and/or integration tests will be running:

```
mvn verify -DskipUTs
```

only integration tests will run but not unit tests.

```
mvn verify -DskipITs
```

only unit tests will run but no integration tests.

All without any profile nor separate test source directory etc.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for a long post, but I guess there is no need to give a lecture on how to use failsafe. I don't need failsafe, I don't want failsafe. I regret that I used the word 'Integration Test'. What I said was 'like integration test'. But in my case I don't allocate any resources that has to be cleaned up, which is the main point of failsafe. What I need is to split my unit tests by folders and run them according to Maven profiles. As easy as that.

Comment: The usage and intention of maven-failsafe-plugin is to run integration tests. It depends what you call an integration test. You should not use surefire plugin only because the intention for surefire is to run the unit tests only. failsafe can be used for different kind of tests (integration test, e2e test etc. and such tests as you describe them). failsafe has nothing to do with resources.  About splitting up by folder (makes from my point of view not much sense) but can be achieved because a folder is a package so you can configure the suites accordingly.

Comment: Naming the tests is a better way and using `@DisplayName` etc. but if you a lot of such tests cases a categorization might be a way to go via package. But you might use tags of junit jupiter to categorize them.. but of course that's just a matter of taste. maybe you can give some examples of your tests based on directory?